# What is a good way to let the user change screen layout?

Tags: layout, toggle

I have 2 layouts. A 1/3 2/3 Sectioned layout and a Full 3/3 Layout. I want the user to be able to change between the two. Right now I have this in the header:[image]

Is there a better or more accepted way of doing this?

Comment: Please provide more information about the target audience, type of application, difference between the two layouts in terms of functions and content, whether the chosen layout persists, etc.  Why are you providing this function?  This will help you determine visual, optimal level of emphasis, wording/verbiage if needed, etc. :-)

Comment: This is a tool for a worker to use when trying to setup a system. The controls appear in the left pane. Results and information occupy the main section. It depends if you want to hide the controls or not.

Comment: Can I ask why you wont just do the slider that will allow the user to change the width of the windows?

Answer (score 2):

Your two layouts are very similar to a page with a left sidebar. If this is the case, you can just use a sidebar toggle button to open/close it.

Another option is to add a dropdown menu `| LAYOUT \/ |` to the header, where you can list the two layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could show a swipe icon and the two views could swipe in and out. Like the sidebar could be swiped away and swipe back.

Answer (score 0):

Icons you are using are used in most of todays website builders (Cornerstone, Elementor, Divi, Visual Composer...), so I think they are good. 
 
Placement of that change option depends on general context of the whole interface.